# How to read a .blm file in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a blm file that I need to be able to read in PHP, I have tried looking into it but there does not seem to be much information on this.

I want to put the file into an array.

Here is some of blm file.

```
#HEADER#
Version : 3
EOF : '^'
EOR : '~'

#DEFINITION#
AGENT_REF^ADDRESS_1^ADDRESS_2^ADDRESS_3^ADDRESS_4^TOWN^POSTCODE1^POSTCODE2^FEATURE1^FEATURE2^FEATURE3^FEATURE4^FEATURE5^FEATURE6^FEATURE7^FEATURE8^FEATURE9^FEATURE10^SUMMARY^DESCRIPTION^BRANCH_ID^STATUS_ID^BEDROOMS^PRICE^PRICE_QUALIFIER^PROP_SUB_ID^CREATE_DATE^UPDATE_DATE^DISPLAY_ADDRESS^PUBLISHED_FLAG^LET_DATE_AVAILABLE^LET_BOND^LET_TYPE_ID^LET_FURN_ID^LET_RENT_FREQUENCY^TRANS_TYPE_ID^NEW_HOME_FLAG^MEDIA_IMAGE_00^MEDIA_IMAGE_01^MEDIA_IMAGE_02^MEDIA_IMAGE_03^MEDIA_IMAGE_04^MEDIA_IMAGE_05^MEDIA_IMAGE_06^MEDIA_IMAGE_07^MEDIA_IMAGE_08^MEDIA_IMAGE_09^MEDIA_IMAGE_10^MEDIA_IMAGE_11^MEDIA_IMAGE_12^MEDIA_IMAGE_13^MEDIA_IMAGE_14^MEDIA_IMAGE_15^MEDIA_IMAGE_16^MEDIA_IMAGE_17^MEDIA_IMAGE_18^MEDIA_IMAGE_19^MEDIA_FLOOR_PLAN_00^MEDIA_FLOOR_PLAN_01^MEDIA_DOCUMENT_00^MEDIA_DOCUMENT_50^MEDIA_DOCUMENT_TEXT_50^MEDIA_IMAGE_60^MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_60^MEDIA_IMAGE_61^MEDIA_IMAGE_TEXT_61^MEDIA_VIRTUAL_TOUR_00~

#DATA#
13450_1063R^Flat 2 - 83^Abbey Road^Llandudno^Borough of Conwy^Llandudno^LL30^2EH^^Spacious Lounge to Front^Security Door Phone^Double Bedroom^Kitchen to Rear with Rear Exit^^Double Glazing Upvc^Gas Central Heating (Combi)^Short walk to Beach/West Shore^Ideal First time Buyer^(Ref.1063) A spacious double-glazed  ground floor self contained flat comprising briefly of spacious lounge, fitted kitchen with cooker and plumbing for autowashing machine, double bedroom and fitted bathroom. Gas central heating with Combi boiler and door security phone. The property is located ...^(Ref.1063) A spacious double-glazed  ground floor self contained flat comprising briefly of spacious lounge, fitted kitchen with cooker and plumbing for autowashing machine, double bedroom and fitted bathroom. Gas central heating with Combi boiler and door security phone. The property is located close to the West Shore in Llandudno. <BR><BR>  <BR>To view this property, please contact our office immediately on (01492) 572213. Similar well maintained properties always required to meet the current demand . . .<BR>^13450^0^1^425^0^8^1998-01-07 00:00:00^2013-04-12 00:00:00^Abbey Road, Llandudno^1^2013-04-01 00:00:00^^1^2^1^2^N^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ~
13450_2590R^Rose Cottage^Pydew Road^Bryn Pydew^Borough of Conwy^Bryn Pydew^LL31^9QB^Semi Detached Cottage^Gas Central Heating/ LPG^Cast Iron Gas Stove^Village Location^1 mile access onto the A55^Large Cottage Garden^Newly Fitted Kitchen^Detached Garage^4 Miles Llandudno^uPVC Double Glazing^(Ref.2590) A delightful 2 bedroomed semi detached cottage situated in the popular village of Bryn Pydew and enjoying countryside views over a lovely country garden. ...^(Ref.2590) A delightful 2 bedroomed semi detached cottage situated in the popular village of Bryn Pydew and enjoying countryside views over a lovely country garden.   <BR>The property is available to let on an Assured Shorthold Tenancy agreement subject to satisfactory financial, credit check and employment references. Sorry no DSS or Smokers. No Pets<BR><BR>Similar well maintained properties always required to meet the current demand.These particulars are believed to be correct but their accuracy is not guaranteed nor do they form part of any contract.<BR>^13450^0^2^520^0^23^2007-07-09 00:00:00^2013-04-13 00:00:00^Pydew Road, Bryn Pydew^1^2012-10-01 00:00:00^620.00^1^2^1^2^N^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ~
13450_2403R^Hedd^Pabo Lane^Llandudno Junction^Borough of Conwy^Llandudno Junction^LL31^9JE^Un-Furnished Detached Cottage^Semi Rural Position^Two Bedrooms^Family Bathroom^Modern Fitted Kitchen^Double Glazing^Off Road Parking^^^^(Ref.2403) *** DETACHED COTTAGE ***situated in a semi rural position with some views and close to local amenities including the A55 expressway at Llandudno Junction giving fast access to Chester, Liverpool and Manchester. The accommodation briefly  consists of entrance porch, hallway, sitting ...^(Ref.2403) *** DETACHED COTTAGE ***situated in a semi rural position with some views and close to local amenities including the A55 expressway at Llandudno Junction giving fast access to Chester, Liverpool and Manchester. The accommodation briefly  consists of entrance porch, hallway, sitting room, kitchen / diner. Two bedrooms and a family bathroom. Externally, the property has off road parking and gardens front and rear.<BR><BR>  <BR>Similar well maintained properties always required to meet the current demand . . . <BR><BR>The property is available to let on an Assured Shorthold Tenancy agreement subject to satisfactory financial, credit check and employment references. Sorry no pets, students, DSS or smokers. <BR><BR>^13450^0^2^550^0^4^2006-05-12 00:00:00^2013-04-08 00:00:00^Pabo Lane, Llandudno Junction^1^2013-05-05 00:00:00^650.00^1^2^1^2^N^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ~
13450_3274S^5^Park Terrace^Deganwy^Conwy^Deganwy^LL31^9UL^Mid Terraced House^Two Bedrooms^Gas Central Heating^Good Location^Close to local amenities^In Need of Modernisation^Close to Railway Station^On Local Bus Route^A55 within 2 miles^** P R I C E D  to  S E L L **^(Ref.3274) ** PRICED TO SELL ** A two bedroomed mid terraced house in need of updating and with room to extend at rear (subject to local authority planning consent).  The property benefits from gas fired central heating with a combi boiler and uPVC double ...^(Ref.3274) ** PRICED TO SELL ** A two bedroomed mid terraced house in need of updating and with room to extend at rear (subject to local authority planning consent).  The property benefits from gas fired central heating with a combi boiler and uPVC double glazing.  <BR>Similar properties always required to meet the current demand .These particulars are believed to be correct but their accuracy is not guaranteed nor do they form part of any contract.<BR>^13450^0^2^75000^0^1^2013-01-04 00:00:00^2013-04-18 00:00:00^Park Terrace, Deganwy^1^2013-01-04 00:00:00^^1^0^1^1^N^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ~
13450_1863S^Flat 2, 24^Kings Road, West End^Colwyn Bay^Borough of Conwy^Colwyn Bay^LL29^7YG^2 Bedroomed Ground Floor Flat^Modern Fitted Bathroom^Modern Fitted Kitchen^New C/htg boiler May 2011^2 Double Bedrooms^Lounge & Reception Room^Close to amenities in West End^A55 within 1 mile^Newly Decorated Throughout^Off Road Parking^(Ref:1863) An unfurnished  two bedroomed ground floor self contained flat located on Kings Road at the West End of Colwyn Bay. Garden area to front with garage to rear and comprising of modern fitted Beech effect kitchen, lounge, modern 3-piece bathroom and combination gas fired central heating ...^(Ref:1863) An unfurnished  two bedroomed ground floor self contained flat located on Kings Road at the West End of Colwyn Bay. Garden area to front with garage to rear and comprising of modern fitted Beech effect kitchen, lounge, modern 3-piece bathroom and combination gas fired central heating boiler. Double main bedroom with smaller 2nd bedroom which could be used as a study. The property has been refurbished, May 2011.  <BR>The property is available to let on an Assured Shorthold Tenancy agreement subject to satisfactory financial, credit check and employment references. Sorry no pets, DSS or smokers.   To view this property, please contact our office immediately. Similar well maintained properties always required  to meet the current demand.<BR>^13450^0^2^94950^0^7^2003-02-21 00:00:00^2013-01-21 00:00:00^Kings Road, West End, Colwyn Bay^1^2012-12-17 00:00:00^^1^2^1^1^N^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ~
13450_2245S^9^Oswald Road^Llandudno Junction^Borough of Conwy^Llandudno Junction^LL31^9EP^Modernised Terraced House^Two Bedrooms^Two Reception Rooms^uPVC Double Glazing^Gas Fired Central Heating^Modern Fitted Kitchen^Modern Fitted Bathroom^Fast Access to A55^^^(Ref.2245) A modernised 2 bedroomed, 2 reception mid terrace house with the benefit of uPVC double glazing and gas fired central heating. Modern kitchen and bathroom all in excellent order throughout.  Situated on a residential street of similar type properties just off the main Conwy Road and ...^(Ref.2245) A modernised 2 bedroomed, 2 reception mid terrace house with the benefit of uPVC double glazing and gas fired central heating. Modern kitchen and bathroom all in excellent order throughout.  Situated on a residential street of similar type properties just off the main Conwy Road and within half a miles access onto the A55 Expressway and within 4 miles of the resort town of Llandudno.<BR>  <BR>The property is available to let on an Assured Shorthold Tenancy agreement subject to satisfactory financial, credit check and employment references.No Pets, sorry no children, students, DSS or Smokers.<BR><BR>Similar well maintained properties always required to meet the current demand.These particulars are believed to be correct but their accuracy is not guaranteed nor do they form part of any contract.<BR>^13450^0^2^95500^0^1^2005-05-05 00:00:00^2013-03-07 00:00:00^Oswald Road, Llandudno Junction^1^2010-08-03 00:00:00^^1^2^1^1^N^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^13450_2245s_flp_00.jpg^ ^ ^ ^ ^13450_2245s_img_60.jpg^EPC^13450_2245s_img_61.jpg^EPC^ ~
13450_3238S^24^Broad Street^Llandudno Junction^Borough of Conwy^Llandudno Junction^LL31^9HG^A Mid terraced House^Upvc Double Glazing^Gas Central Heating^Two Reception Rooms^Two Double Bedrooms^Small rear Yard^200 Yards from Railway Station^A55 within 1 Mile^Llandudno 4 Miles away^^(Ref.3238) A Two Bedroomed mid terraced house with the benefit of Gas Fired Central Heating and Upvc Double Glazing. There is a Mainline Railway Dtation 200 yards away and the A55 Expressway is within one ...^(Ref.3238) A Two Bedroomed mid terraced house with the benefit of Gas Fired Central Heating and Upvc Double Glazing. There is a Mainline Railway Dtation 200 yards away and the A55 Expressway is within one mile.  <BR>Similar properties always required to meet the current demand .These particulars are believed to be correct but their accuracy is not guaranteed nor do they form part of any contract.<BR>^13450^0^2^97500^0^1^2012-07-30 00:00:00^2012-11-30 00:00:00^Broad Street, Llandudno Junction^1^2012-07-30 00:00:00^^1^2^1^1^N^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ~
13450_3209S^16^Glan Y Mor Road^Llandudno Junction^Borough of Conwy^Llandudno Junction^LL31^9SB^Gas Central Heating^Upvc Double Glazing^Views to Conwy Castle^Loft Coversion/Hobbies Room^Close to Shops and Station^A55 within one mile^Two Reception Rooms^Parking space to front^Small front Garden^Ideal 1st time buyers home^(Ref.3209) A semi detached modernised railwayman's cootage with the benefit of Gas Fired central heating with a combi boiler and Upvc double glazing. There are two Double Bedrooms and a converted loft currently utilised as a bedroom triple aspect  wuith views to Deganwy and  a view of Conwy ...^(Ref.3209) A semi detached modernised railwayman's cootage with the benefit of Gas Fired central heating with a combi boiler and Upvc double glazing. There are two Double Bedrooms and a converted loft currently utilised as a bedroom triple aspect  wuith views to Deganwy and  a view of Conwy Castle. The property is on a row of similar cottages on the side of the railway line on the edge of the Conwy Estuary with views across the Estuary. The Line is for a local service between the mainline railway station at Llandudno Junction and the town of Llandudno.   <BR>Similar properties always required to meet the current demand .These particulars are believed to be correct but their accuracy is not guaranteed nor do they form part of any contract.<BR>^13450^0^2^98500^0^3^2012-03-13 00:00:00^2013-03-16 00:00:00^Glan Y Mor Road, Llandudno Junction^1^2012-03-13 00:00:00^^1^2^1^1^N^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ~
13450_3211S^5^Dol Goed^Llandudno Junction^Borough of Conwy^Llandudno Junction^LL31^9LH^Detached Bugalow^Private Front Garden^Two Double Bedrooms^Good Sized Garden^Detached Single Garage^On Level for Local Bus Service^A 55 within One Mile^Rental Potential Circ £600 pcm^^^(Ref.3211)  ** PRICED TO SELL ** Offers invited over £100.00 for this detached 2 Bedroomed  with great potential and Rental Potential. ...^(Ref.3211)  ** PRICED TO SELL ** Offers invited over £100.00 for this detached 2 Bedroomed  with great potential and Rental Potential.   <BR>Similar properties always required to meet the current demand .These particulars are believed to be correct but their accuracy is not guaranteed nor do they form part of any contract.<BR>^13450^0^2^115000^10^12^2012-03-26 00:00:00^2013-02-11 00:00:00^Dol Goed, Llandudno Junction^1^2012-03-26 00:00:00^^1^2^1^1^N^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ~
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: as long as the BLM file's format is consistent (AFAIK they are like CSVs), you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php or https://php.net/fread

Comment: Thanks for the response Alex, I have tried this and still cannot get it to work. I have added a snippet of the code to show how it has been saved.

Comment: I saw this and I was wondering... what's a BLM file? Turns out it is a file format used by real estate agents to upload data about properties for sale to the UK property website RightMove – https://www.rightmove.co.uk/ps/pdf/guides/RightmoveDatafeedFormatV3iOVS_1.6.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be a help looking at your input file:

```
<?php
$row = 1;

# Put your file instead of file.blm
if (($handle = fopen("file.blm", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "^")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;

         for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                if($data[0] == '13450') { echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n"; }
        }
     }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

?>

Further looking into your file, you probably want to add something like this too:

```
if($data[0] == '13450') { /*print results */ }
```

This would only list the rows you are probably looking for - starting with 13450 in the data section

You can read more about fgetcsv here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried doing this and nothing seems to happen. I dont think the file is being read.

Comment: Is the .blm file and the .php file in the same directory?

Comment: Your code was correct, I had the file placed in the themes folder but it needed to be placed in the root.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This helped a lot getting me on the right track. I had to expand it, though, to create a file header and to implement delimiters, separators and end-of-lines. Also, I increased 1000 to 100000 to account for long lines :)